# Is it possible to recover from corrupted libc on Redhat?

Tags: rhel, glibc, system-recovery

I have created the following unfortunate situation.

While trying to resolve this error when running a binary :

```
/lib64/libc.so.6 : version 'GLIBC_2.15' not found
```

Looking further I found that `libc.so.6` pointed to :

```
libc.so.6 -> libc-2.12.so
```

So I thought it would be OK to just put `libc-2.19.so` into `/usr/local/lib` and run `ldconfig` to 'override' this. Now, all of these commands lead to segfault : `ls, rm, mv, less, chown, chmod`  ...

Only `cd` and `pwd` seem to work.

Is there any way to recover this machine ? Or do I just need to reinstall Linux ?

Thank you. (P.s. I can't check the Redhat version anymore since no command seems to work ... )

Comment: You could boot a live system, mount your partition and remove the file in `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: I'd also be concerned about what *else* is broken.  How did `libc` apparently get replaced like that?  And to check the version, after you boot from CD, you can read the contents of `/etc/release`.  One thing, though - since `libc` is wrong, the contents of `/etc/release` could *also* be wrong.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for your suggestion. This seems to be the right approach.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am trying to run a binary that requires glib 2.15 or higher, but my company is running some very old version of Redhat and very old kernel that I am not allowed to update, so I was trying to hack my way to getting the binary running and put a new libc in /usr/local/lib.